# Regular Expressions for a password with politics

Tags: javascript

My password has to have at least 6 characters with upper and lower case letters and at least one number or a special character, I do not know how to make them one or the other, i made this regular expression but if i don´t put a number and a special character it don´t send

```
var password=/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]/
```

Comment: Multiple, independent conditions are rarely best tested using a **single** regular expression.

Comment: So i hve to do a regular expression for the numbers and the special characters and then made something like if(password.match(numbers) || password.match(specialchar){

Comment: i´m starting in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are trying to do, by assuming minimum characters 6 and maximum 20, you can try the following regex:

`var regex = /^(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,20}$/;`

Comment: It's my pleasure.